# When does an algorithm become considered artificial intelligence?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I understand that an algorithm is a set of instructions. Ai is essentially the same thing, only, more complicated? Let's say I use a minmax algorithm to allow moves to be played on a tic tac toe board, generally people would consider this ai. But if I implement an algorithm to solve a rubiks cube, is that considered ai?

I guess what I'm asking is, is it the complexity of the algorithm, the fact that situations change on the fly in an algorithm, the ignorance of the user/programmer as to how the algorithm works or all/some of the above? Or am I missing something?

I feel like this field is quite arbitrary. I imagine for good reason.I imagine because complexity is complex.

Comment: AI is when the result is uncertain and cannot be explained, and the algorithm can build upon earlier attempts to get improved persistent parameters. Like a neural net. To explain AI to managers please use an entirely different wording. Minimax, linear optimisation are _not_ really AI. They are logical.

Comment: Not sure why I would be explaining ai to managers, but ok. Would you say that ai is machine learning entirely?

Comment: I mentioned managers as the term AI got both highly inflated, and applied to every propagated project. But yes, **learning** is one keyword. Quantum computing might in ten years also come into play. Basically **intelligence** is _the ability to acquire and apply knowledge and skills._ Chess programs in general are not AI but based on mass data (statistics). But others might see it differently.

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed quite arbitrary.

If you consult wikipedia you might find following definition which in my personal opinion catches the load quite accurately:

> Computer science defines AI research as the study of "intelligent
>   agents": any device that perceives its environment and takes actions
>   that maximize its chance of successfully achieving its goals. A more
>   elaborate definition characterizes AI as "a system's ability to
>   correctly interpret external data, to learn from such data, and to use
>   those learnings to achieve specific goals and tasks through flexible
>   adaptation."

To take your Rubiks Cube as an example, there would be at least 2 ways you could write the algoritm to solve the puzzle. Firstly, any cube can be solved by following a hardcoded path or set of instructions once you have a certain start position. Implementing this would not be considered AI in my opinion as the machine itself is not learning anything. It just follows a well defined path of instructions till the end.

A second way to implement this would be to have the program just start solving it randomly. But the machine remembers it's moves, and learns the most effective path to reach the solution. When solving the next cube, the machine can build upon this newly learned information to solve it faster and again learn from this iteration to improve it's algorithm.

So in short, as far as I'm concerned, it can be considered AI when a machine is capable of optimizing/extending its own algorithms to become more efficient in its tasks.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. What you said made sense, but the emphasis on machine learning is what gets me. Surely you could have an intelligent agent without it having to learn?

Comment: Would you say that ai is machine learning? I feel like this topic is covered alot(there's alot of opinions on the Web =p). I think I'd take a different approach and say, if the machine can exhibit human like behavior. Hard coded or not. If it can trick the user into thinking its an intelligent system then it is.